# How can I retrieve AD Username in .NET Core hosted on Azure Web App?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory, windows-authentication

I have used HTTPContext.User.Identity.Name to get the current users name.  It works via localhost but returns null on Azure Web App.

HTTPContext.User.Identity.Name has worked before when using .Net Framework but I am now using .Net Core which doesn't work.

Current code:

```cs
private void SetUpUser()
{
    var identityName = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
    identityName = identityName.Replace("@example.com", "").Replace(".", "").Replace("example\\", "");
    string userName = identityName.Replace(".", "");
}
```

Error message:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   CommissionInputApp.Controllers.HomeController.SetUpUser() in HomeController.cs

Comment: How have you configured authentication?

Comment: Azure Active Directory which uses our internal AD (internal application)

Comment: Can you add the code where you configure AAD authentication?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, we have used HTTPContext.User.Identity.Name in previous apps, and this is the first time it isn't working when deployed

Comment: Azure AD authentication has to be configured somewhere, whether it is in the code or through Authentication/Authorization on the App Service. The App Service isn't joined to your domain (and can't be) so regular Windows authentication does not work there.

Answer (score 0):

Do you set the NameClaimType in OpenIdConnectOptions configuration:

```
options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters() { NameClaimType = "name" };
```

I haven't create my own application & Api , just use fabrikamb2cdomain as code sample provides , even though some method is obsolete in .net core 2.2 , for example ,cache.HasStateChanged . The authecation still works and get correct name with User.Identity.Name , HttpContext.User.Claims also be set :

[image]

Also you can provide more details and code to us to reproduce the issue.